# p:commandButton action not working in p:confirmDialog

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog

I have a functionality where I have to call my managed bean through my confirmation dialog box which is for delete button. When the user clicks on delete button there is a confirmation dialog box that pops up and `onclick` of "Yes" my relative managed bean should get called. But I am not able to do it.

```
<p:commandButton id="Delete" action="#{tbeanId.delete}" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" 
   value="Delete" title="GDeleteButton" ajax="false" onclick="PF('groupDeleteConfirm').show();" type="button">
   <p:confirm header="Delete Record" message="Are you sure about deleting this record?" icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
</p:commandButton>

<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" widgetVar="groupDeleteConfirm">
   <p:commandButton title="GDelYesButton" value="Yes" oncomplete="PF('groupDeleteConfirm').hide()" " />
   <p:commandButton title="GDelNoButton" value="No" onclick="PF('groupDeleteConfirm').hide()" type="button" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you use the `p:confirmDialog` with `global="true"` the confirm/cancel buttons are (somewhat unintuitively) identified by these 2 styleClasses:

```
styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"
styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no"
```

Then the action will be called and show()/hide() will happen automatically. Ajax should be true on the main button and you don't need `type="button"` so all in all it will be much simpler:

```
<p:commandButton id="delete" 
                 action="#{trafficExpenseItemsMBean.deleteExpenseItemsGroup}" 
                 icon="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" 
                 value="Delete" 
                 title="GDeleteButton">
    <p:confirm header="Delete Record" 
               message="Are you sure about deleting this record?" 
               icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
</p:commandButton>

<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">
    <p:commandButton title="GDelYesButton" value="Yes" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"/>
    <p:commandButton title="GDelNoButton" value="No" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Another option would be to make it non-global. Then you'd need to move the action to the yes-button and the message to the p:confirmDialog as in

```
<p:commandButton id="delete" 
                 icon="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" 
                 value="Delete" 
                 title="GDeleteButton"
                 onclick="PF('groupDeleteConfirm').show()">
</p:commandButton>
<p:confirmDialog message="Are you sure about deleting this record?" 
                 showEffect="fade"
                 hideEffect="explode" 
                 widgetVar="groupDeleteConfirm">
    <p:commandButton title="GDelYesButton" 
                     value="Yes" 
                     action="#{trafficExpenseItemsMBean.deleteExpenseItemsGroup}" 
                     oncomplete="PF('groupDeleteConfirm').hide()" 
                     update=":growl"/>
    <p:commandButton title="GDelNoButton" 
                     value="No" 
                     oncomplete="PF('groupDeleteConfirm').hide()"/>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

I'm not sure you really want those `title`'s on the buttons though, as they are shown to the user.

Comment: Jaqen:I appreciate your answer on JSF. I had one similar problem faced as mentioned this question. Can you pls help me out. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998212/clear-grid-on-click-of-yes-button-in-confirmation-dialog-box

Answer (score 5):

When you use a `p:commandButton` for the action that needs to be done on the server, you can not use `type="button"` because that is for **Push buttons** which are used to execute custom javascript without causing an ajax/non-ajax request to the server.

For this purpose, you can dispense the **type** attribute (default value is "submit") or you can explicitly use `type="submit"`.

Hope this will help someone!