# Clear grid on click of Yes button in confirmation dialog box

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF in which i have a functionality to delete a particular row of a grid. I am using panel grid. On click of delete button i get a confirmation dialog box on click of yes which the row should be deleted and the grid should be refreshed. I am able to delete the row however the grid does not get refreshed or clear.
Below is my JSF Code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<p:commandButton id="delete"
  icon="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"
  action="#{trafficExpenseItemsMBean.deleteTrafficExpenseItemRow}"
  onclick="setSelectedRowId('rowId',#{trafficSearchResult.id})"
  title="GDeleteButton">
  <p:confirm header="Delete Record"
    message="Are you sure about deleting this record?"
    icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
</p:commandButton>

<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade">
  <p:commandButton title="GDelYesButton" value="Yes" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"/>
  <p:commandButton title="GDelNoButton" value="No"  onclick="PF('confirmation').hide()" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: I think you just need to update the panelGrid - have you tried update="idOfPanelGrid" on the first commandButton? A commandButton by default updates nothing

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar: yes i did try that but it doesnt work. Can you suggest some other way?

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correclty u back the data in a managed bean u need to call a certain function of that bean with the given id and the managed bean itself would handle the operation. so after u set the rowId from ur setSelectedRowId('rowId',#{trafficSearchResult.id}) call.
on confirmation button u need to call the proper delete method, and update the grid component based on its widget id for example:

```
 <p:commandButton title="GDelYesButton" value="Yes" onclick="bean.removeItem()" oncomplete = "PF('datagrid_widget_id').update() PF('confirmation').hide()"/>
```