# p:commandButton p:confirm actionListener not triggering

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, dialog, actionlistener, confirm

Primefaces actionListener is not working in p:confirmDialog . Can someone help? The saveRecord works fine in a simple dialog box.

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{EmployeeDetailsComponent.displayInfo}">
    <p:confirm header="Attention" message="test" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
</p:commandButton>

<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" appendToBody="true">
    <p:commandButton value="Save"  action="#{TestComponent.saveRecord(TestComponent.testData)}" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
    <p:commandButton value="Cancel" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: **Duplicate**
Please, see this post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957293/pcommandbutton-action-not-working-in-pconfirmdialog

Answer (score 2):

You have `appendToBody="true"`, which means there is no `<h:form>` to handle the click because the whole dialog content is moved directly under `body`. Just add the form inside the dialog.

```
<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" appendToBody="true">    
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="Save"  action="#{TestComponent.saveRecord(TestComponent.testData)}" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />      
    </h:form>    
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: @Samantha Is your bean named `testComponent` or `TestComponent`? Try it with a lower case, or post bean code

Comment: bean name is good. i have simple save command without dialog, and it works. The problem is with action in dialog.

Answer (score 2):

I just add a div to center the buttons and the process and the action works perfectly, example code with primefaces 5.1:

```
 <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="clip"  >
      <div align="center">
         <p:commandButton value="Aceptar" actionListener="#{bienvenidoUI.asignarPSI()}"  update="tablaProceso" icon="ui-icon-check"   process="@this" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"/>
         <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
      </div>
 </p:confirmDialog>
```

and I just call the confirmDialog from inside a table with:

```
<p:commandButton   icon="ui-icon-circle-check" title="Asignar PSI"  rendered="#{bienvenidoUI.usr.idUsuario==bienvenidoUI.autorizadorId and min.estado.descripcion=='Proceso'}">
       <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{min}" target="#{bienvenidoUI.minutaSelected}"  />
       <p:confirm header="Confirmación" message="Esta seguro que desea asignar psi?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove appendToBody="true" from the confirm dialog component and enclose Save command buttton with in form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <html lang="en">
        <h:head>
        </h:head>
        <h:body id="top">
            <h:form>
                <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{simpleBean.displayInfo}" action="#{simpleBean.saveRecord}">
                    <p:confirm header="Attention" message="test" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </h:form>

            <p:confirmDialog closeOnEscape="true" global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">  
                <p:commandButton value="Save" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Cancel" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no"/>
            </p:confirmDialog>

        </h:body>
    </html>

</f:view>
```

SimpleBean.java

```
@Named("simpleBean")
public class SimpleBean implements Serializable{
   public void displayInfo(){
      Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Display Info works");        
   }
   public String saveRecord(){
      Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Save Record works");        
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: I had tested this on PF5.1 and GF4 and this works. I have provide the complete page and bean for your testing.

Comment: Yes the above code works without including action in save command. I need to add action in save command( see my code). This action is not working

Comment: If you need to add action this should be added to the Save command button of the calling form. Refer the updated code.