# p:confirmDialog is not working when I try to call a method in primefaces with java

Tags: primefaces

I have a button that triggers a method with some code, but now I'm trying to set a confirmation message just in case the user clicks the button by mistake. I see at the primefaces showcase the confirmDialog and I wrote the code but it doesn't work. When I click the button, the confirmation shows up, but when I click on the Yes button nothing happens.

This is my code:

```
    <h:form id="forma" prependId="false">
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />  
        <p:confirmDialog global="true">
            <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" />
            <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" />
        </p:confirmDialog>
        <div align="center">
            <p:commandButton id="botonCveGeo" 
                             value="Iniciar proceso" 
                             style="width:130px;height:25px;" 
                             update="messages"
                             ajax="false"
                             actionListener="#{actCveGeo.procesoActCveGeo()}"
                             title="Inicia proceso de actualizar clave geoestadistica">
                <p:confirm header="Confirm" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
            </p:commandButton>
        </div>
    </h:form>
```

Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [p:commandButton action not working in p:confirmDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957293/pcommandbutton-action-not-working-in-pconfirmdialog)

Comment: I tried that solution yesterday, both options actually and non of these worked for me... The only thing I saw different is that in the solution is commented that ajax should be true, but in this case I need to set ajax as false or the method on the button doesn't make the call

Comment: if you put `ajax=true` this will work . But I don't know If you can make this change

Comment: What is you primefaces version?

Comment: I'm currently using PF 7.0, I set ajax="true" but it is also not working, I'm thinking it could be some configuration of the platform I'm working with

Comment: @JuanPabloMacias your code with `ajax="true"` in my project is working with PF 7

Comment: Then It should be a problem with the company platform I'm working with. I'm gonna need to review this with them. Thanks tsotzolas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@tsotzolas is correct this is your problem already reported in PF: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/99

You currently can't use `ajax=false` with the confirm dialog behavior.

Please go upvote that issue if you clearly need this behavior.

Comment: I tried to adapt the code from the link to mine but I only refresh the page and the method still doesn't fire

Comment: I think it needs to be fixed at its core, i have never attempted any workarounds.